# iOS: как поменять местами записи в БД?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

В приложении пользователь в `UITableView` может менять местами `UITableViewCell`, которые в свою очередь заполняются данными из БД.

Каким образом при этом действии пользователя можно поменять местами записи и в самой БД?

Answer (score 2):

Если данные предоставляет Core Data и наполнение `UITableView` делается с `NSFetchedResultsController`, то надо:

1. Указать для FRCшного `fetchRequest` сортировку по атрибуту вроде `index`.
2. При перетаскивании ячеек обновлять значения атрибута `index` у объектов, соответствующих затронутым ячейкам.
3. FRC поймает эти изменения, и если реализована классическая схема взаимодействия FRC и UITableView – эти изменения будут отражены в таблице.